# wordpress: how and from can i modify newsletter plugin and sidebar widgets theming?

Tags: wordpress

1st i had installed newsletter plugin and put its widget on sidebar.
It has two input fields by default, one for email and one for name,
But wat i want is, only the email field mean no name field.
so how can i remove that, though i did spent a lot of time in finding for the appropriate code but didn't find any.
2nd thing is where i can modify my sidebar widgets theming mean where they coming from as they are not in sidebar.php ???
cuz i added primary widget category and recent jobs so where can i theme theme

Comment: You change the appearance by editing the stylesheet (style.css) in your theme. You need only view the HTML source of your page, not the PHP source files, to determine what classes/id's are available to target with CSS. As for editing the newsletter plugin, who knows, we're not psychic and don't even know which one you installed. Unless you are writing your own code and can share it here, this isn't a real question for StackOverflow.

Comment: This sounds like more of a general implementation question -- try posting to: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com. To learn how to code for WordPress, try: http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

Comment: tnx andrew :) this is much more helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the style sheets for plug ins (i.e. sidebar widgets), by clicking the word Editor in the Plug ins group in the sidebar of your admin panel.

Here is a cropped screenshot of what I am talking about, let me know if you need more instructions than this.

[image]